# rename files in rar file without extract it

Tags: archiving, rar

I want to rename or delete files or folders in a .rar file?

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

[WinRAR](http://www.rarlab.com/download.htm) has such a feature. Double click on the RAR file, select the file you like to rename, hit <kbd>F2</kbd> and change the file name. When you hit Enter, the archive will automatically be updated.

Comment: my files are multipart. so I can use your method ... I need a help!!! please help me!!!!

Answer (score 1):

On mac/linux command line rar has a switch to rename files in the archive:

`rar rn archive.rar filename newfilename`

On windows using WinRar you can select a file inside it and press F2 to rename it!

Comment: I want to rename a file in a rar file, when I open the rar file and select a file in that archive, after pressing "F2", nothing happened.